# storing big numbers (10-12 digits ) in an unordered map <string, int>

Tags: c++, unordered-map

how do I store big numbers (10 digits long ) as values for keys in an unordered map in C++.I get this warning- "warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow] ".All the values for the corresponding keys are printed  different from what they were initialised.

Comment: Try `long long` instead of `int`.

Comment: `<cstdint>`, and `uint64_t` or `int64_t` (depending on your value domain), would probably come in pretty handy.

Answer (score 1):

On typical modern hardware, `int` has 32 bit, which would allow, in two's complement, for values in range of [-2 147 483 648; 2 147 483 647]. If your values don't fit into this range, you need a larger data type.

Be aware, though, that the standard only guarantees a much smaller range of [-32767; 32767], and actually there exists hardware only using 16 bit for `int` *even today* (if you wonder why not -32768: Well, standard covers architectures based on one's complement or sign magnitude as well...).

Typically, long has 32-bit range (which is standard's minimum) as well (but e. g. on 64-bit linux, it has 64 bit), and long long is guaranteed to be at least as large as 64 bit.

Quite a mess, as you see... If you need guaranteed range, best thing you can do is using the data types from `<cstdint>` header, like `int64_t` (or – if you don't deal with negative values – preferrably `uint64_t`).

There are quite a number of other useful types, e. g. `uint_least8_t` (smallest data type that has at least 8 bits – if you write portable code and need to cover platforms that might not be able to provide `uint8_t`) or `uint_fast8_t` (data type with at least 8 bit that can be accessed fastest on given platform; pretty often, this is larger than `uint8_t`). Got curious? Why not read a bit [further](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)?

Answer (score -3):

in c++ int can store this much

int     4bytes  -2147483648 to 2147483647

long int (or long long) can store   -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807

or you can just  go for unsigned long int which can store from  0 to 18446744073709551615

for a larger number then that you can try boost libraries or try to make a string based function that can save it and convert it for math operations when you need it

Comment: Be aware that the range for `int` is only the range on *typical modern hardware*, but can actually even be smaller (and yes, there are 16-bit machines out there even today!). Minimum range guaranteed by the standard only is [-32767, 32767], and yes, lower bound is negative of upper bound (such that you could cover one's complement or sign magnitude).

Comment: C++ requires only that `int` is at least 16bit and `(unsigned) long` is only required to be at least 32bit, it varies between that and 64bit on common x86_64 platforms. Only `(unsigned) long long` is required to be at least 64bit on all platforms.